# Iniciar novamente o requestLocationUpdates() com Sleep

Tags: java, android, thread

Como faço para iniciar o `requestLocationUpdates()` com `Thread.sleep();` no `Android`?

Meu código:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("pontos.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);       
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO pontos(latitude, longitude, datahora) VALUES('"+ loc.getLatitude()+"','"+loc.getLongitude()+"','"+  sdf.format(d)+"')");

   db.close();
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Atualizado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
 locationManager.removeUpdates(this);   
  incremento();



}

private void incremento() {
     new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
          public void run() {

               try {

                  Thread.sleep(5000);
                                      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new Servico());

               }catch(Exception e){}

                 }
            }).start(); 


}
```

Eu chamo o `incremento();` no final de `onLocationChanged()`, mas nada acontece.
Detalhe: esse é um serviço em Background.

Comment: Seria muito interessante você colocar algum printStackTrace ou mesmo que fosse um System.out.println dentro do catch, porque você está "engolindo" a exceção. Se estiver acontecendo alguma coisa de errada você não vai ver o que foi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Como funcionam LocationManager e LocationListener

O método `LocationListener.onLocationChanged()` é chamado sempre que houver uma nova posição obtida por GPS ou triangulação de antenas disponível (dependendo se você passou `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` ou `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` para `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`).

A execução de `onLocationChanged()` não depende de quantas vezes é chamado `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`; este último somente precisa ser chamado uma vez, e a partir daí o método `onLocationChanged()` será chamado repetidas vezes sempre que houver uma posição nova disponível.

O método `onLocationChanged()` será sempre executado no thread principal e, se não me falha a memória, o método `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` também deve ser chamado a partir do thread principal.

Passe `this` para ele ao invés de `new Servico()`, e não espere que ele produzirá posições cada vez que for chamado, isto é, não o combine com `Thread.sleep()` porque não é assim que ele funciona. O recebimento de posições irá parar quando você chamar `locationManager.removeUpdates(this)`.

### Sugestão de uso

Inicie o seu serviço de captura de posições chamando `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` e, assim que for chamado `onLocationChanged()`, chame em seguida `locationManager.removeUpdates(this)` para interromper a obtenção de posições. Guarde a posição obtida no banco e agende a próxima execução do serviço para algum tempo no futuro por meio da classe [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Desta forma o serviço será executado uma vez para cada captura de posição. Se souber de antemão de quanto em quanto tempo deseja chamar o serviço, faça esse agendamento via `AlarmManager` com o método `setRepeating()`.

Comment: Excelente explicação Piovezan. tu pode me informar como usar AlarmManager no meu script ?

Comment: @EmersonBarcellos Veja esse exemplo simples: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Comment: Qual serviço devo agendar? todo ou só o `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`? desculpe sou novo em java e obrigado pela compreensão.

Comment: Ok já resolvi aqui, as dicas me ajudaram a resolver. muito obrigado Piovezan